# Grid alignment inside ComboBox selection

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

I'm trying to customize the content I display inside a combobox. The source that I have is the following for the combobox definition:

```
<ComboBox
x:Name="ServicesComboBox"
Margin="36,220,36,0"
VerticalAlignment="Top"
SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" 
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MetricService}"
BorderBrush="#CC000000">
```

The itemtemplate I'm using is the following:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MetricService">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MetricsName}" FontSize="16"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MetricsProvider}" Foreground="#FF878787" 
                       FontSize="16" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The result is this image:

[image: Combobox with value]

The problem happens when I click the combobox, and what I see is this:

[image: Combobox selection]

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the HorizontalContentAlignment of items to Stretch like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ServicesComboBox"
            Margin="36,220,36,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            BorderBrush="#CC000000"
            SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MetricService}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```